# Change the equation of the Gauss bell

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

My goal is to draw the absorption peaks of Lambert-Beer-Bouguer graph which, ideally, have the shape of a Gaussian. I would like to make sure that these peaks all have the same width, which in Gauss's equation depends on sigma, and I could change its height.
Something like

```
\gauss{9}{1}
```

Where `9` is the symmetry axis (mu) and `1` is the height of the peak.
How can I modify the equation to achieve this?

```
\newcommand\gauss[2]{1/(sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))} % Gauss function, parameters mu and sigma
```

Comment: Sounds like a *math* and not like a *LaTeX* question ...

Comment: https://www.thoughtco.com/normal-distribution-bell-curve-formula-3126278 -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#:~:text=Gaussian%20funct